# How to print weather when the checkbox is checked in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am creating a web app with angularJS. Here I have a checkbox which looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="clickcheck()" ng-model="checkall" />
```

In my controller I have a function for checkbox check:

```
$scope.clickcheck = function() {
    console.log(/* print wether if my checkbox is checked or not on checkbox click */);
}
```

What do I need to do here? I just want to print whether when my checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-model="checkall"` already does the job for you:

```
$scope.clickcheck = function() {
    if(checkall) { 
        console.log('Checkbox is checked!'); //Print weather here
    } else {
        console.log('Checkbox is not checked');
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did the same sir :)

Thank You A Lot

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead of `ngClick` and as you have already attachec `ngModel` i.e. `checkall`, it will evaluate to `true` when checkbox is `checked`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="clickcheck()" ng-model="checkall" />
```

In controller

```
$scope.clickchech=function(){
    console.log($scope.checkall ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkbox value is in `$scope.checkall` variable

```
console.log($scope.checkall);
```